# How to set custom value axisLeft on mpandroidchart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I created a bar chart by `MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3`.as you can see on my picture

[image]

On AxisLeft, there are a big numbers. this is my codes:

```
YAxis yAxis = mBinding.barChartIncome.getAxisLeft();
yAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
yAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART);
yAxis.setSpaceTop(15f);
yAxis.setTextSize(12f);
yAxis.setAxisMinimum(1f);
yAxis.setLabelCount(10, false);
```

Now, I want to dived these big numbers into 1,000,000 and then shown on chart?How could i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `IAxisValueFormatter` for this. Create class that implements it like this:

```
public class MyYAxisValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            return String.valueOf(value/1000000);  // Format value, and get any string here
        }
}
```

And set it to your chart's **Left** axis :

```
chart.getAxisLeft().setValueFormatter(new MyYAxisValueFormatter());
```